# How to hide or move scroll in scss?

Tags: html, css

This is my `scss` code:

```
#select-ul-country {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: #434342;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  #select-li-country {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  }
}
```

And here is how it looks like, how can I hide or move left that scroll bar:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
#select-ul-country::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
#select-ul-country {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```